# WSO2IS Error adding new workflow definition

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm following the tutorial steps in 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Adding+a+New+Workflow+Definition

but when I try to save the new definition I got an error.
Someone can help me to understand where is my fault?
This is the log error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-17 13:53:57,698] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method addWorkflow 
            java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
                at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
                at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
                at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
                at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
                at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
                at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
                at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
                at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
                at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.mgt.stub.WorkflowAdminServiceStub.addWorkflow(WorkflowAdminServiceStub.java:3368)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.mgt.ui.WorkflowAdminServiceClient.addWorkflow(WorkflowAdminServiceClient.java:150)
                at org.apache.jsp.workflow_002dmgt.finish_002dwf_002dwizard_jsp._jspService(finish_002dwf_002dwizard_jsp.java:120)
                at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
                at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
                at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
                at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
                at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
                at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor286.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
                at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
                at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
                at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
                at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
                at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
                at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
                at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
                at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
                at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
                at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
                at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
                at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
                at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1906)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:759)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.BPELDeployer.removePlaceHolders(BPELDeployer.java:207)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.BPELDeployer.generateProcessArtifact(BPELDeployer.java:234)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.BPELDeployer.generateAndDeployArtifacts(BPELDeployer.java:124)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.BPELDeployer.initialize(BPELDeployer.java:108)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.mgt.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.deploy(AbstractWorkflow.java:86)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.ApprovalWorkflow.deploy(ApprovalWorkflow.java:84)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.mgt.WorkflowManagementServiceImpl.addWorkflow(WorkflowManagementServiceImpl.java:364)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.mgt.WorkflowManagementAdminService.addWorkflow(WorkflowManagementAdminService.java:233)
                ... 135 more
```

Comment: Are you using windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is a known issue [1] in IS 5.1.0 version with windows OS. This is fixed in the current releases.

You can download IS 5.2.0 beta version from [2] as the issue is solved in that version.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4279

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.2.0-beta

Comment: Hi! I have downloded this version and followed this guide to setup IS with AM:  
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0    
Now IS server hangs with this log repeated many times:    
[2016-06-20 10:27:22,034] WARN{org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:    
[2016-06-20 10:27:22,040]  WARN 
{org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-5.0.3